# ArcGIS Pro's export layout only displays PDFs with an orange/pink hue

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts, pdf

ArcGIS Pro's export layout only displays PDFs with an orange/pink hue. I have reinstalled Pro and other PDF viewers already. All of my color management settings are set to RGB. I already know a couple of ways to get a clean image, but I am looking to figure out why this problem is happening. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

The first image is what should output while the second image is what continues to output.

[image: Image 1]

[image]

Comment: I don't have Pro available anymore to check, but you might look at your background color settings for the map and layout to be sure they aren't the cause.

Comment: It looks like turning on color management is the reason why I have been having this problem.